# How to extract the ip address and physical address a arp table for each device on a network in Python

Tags: python, string, substring, arp

I wrote this piece of code that displays the arp table on a network and it displays the information on multiple lines for each device on the network. I wanted to know if there was a way I can extract the **IP Address** and **Physical Address** for each device and as they are the only parts I need. Here are the codes I used to get the ARP table:

```
for device in os.popen('arp -a'):
    print(device)
```

I am fairly new to Python so I need help on how to get that information from the table we get when these codes are run.

Comment: you get `string` so you can use string functions on it - ie. `split()`, slice `[start:end]`, regex, etc. I would start with `device.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the line on white space and keep the parts that interest you.

```py
for device in os.popen('arp -a'):
    # example output: xxxx (192.168.1.254) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [ether] on wlp..
    _, ip, _, phy, _ = device.split(maxsplit=4)
    # remove the paranthesis around the ip address
    ip = ip.strip('()')
    print(ip, phy)
```

Comment: thank you, the arp table on windows is a bit different but I managed to do it